# python request.get not fetching results when params include # anchor tag

Tags: python, urllib

I've been trying this for quite sometime
My url has # tag

```
url = http://www.firstcry.com/search.aspx?q=blue%20jeans#q=@@@@1@0@20@@&gender=Unisex&PageNo=1
```

When I try `request.get(url)` method, it only fetches for results where url is upto # tag, but the actual url takes time to completely load and gives final set of results (which are different).

How can I avoid this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fragment part of a URI (everything after the '#') is normally interpreted by the browser. That is, the retrieved document is everything up to the '#'. That's what `request.get(url)` actually loads: the **single** file (resource) with that URI.

Now, the browser then "does something" with the fragment -- scrolls to it, most commonly. The browser could do other things with the fragment via javascript.

What it sounds like you're seeing is `requests` gets the file which contains javascript which, on loading, gets additional information based on the fragment.

This is not much different from scraping a dynamic HTML, where the scraped page loads javascript which builds a different DOM.

You'll need to use something like Selenium, or you'll have to manually interpret the results and load additional URLs.

Comment: If you bring up your browser's network request log before visiting the page, you can take a look at the request the browser sends and see that it actually stops before the `#`. (On Chrome, this log can be found by hitting Ctrl-Shift-J and picking the Network tab.)

Comment: Right, @user2357112, That means the server never knows about the fragment!

Comment: Okay...this explanation was pretty useful. I can know change my thinking in the right direction. Thanks a lot pbuck.